# MSAL React is not signing out from application instead it is also signing out from other tabs which are authenticated sessions

Tags: reactjs, azure, logout, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

I am trying to logout the user in my react application which uses MSAL and with user account abc@mod123.onmicrosoft.com.
Now, there is a tab already opened with portal.azure.com for the same user. When the user gets logged out from the React application, while we are changing the tenant or accessing some links in portal.azure.com, it is asking to reenter the credentials for the user that is signed in before.

It means the Logout is happening even for other url which is having authenticated session for the same user , which is in other tab and opened.

Thus, the user is signing out from identity server instead of application. can any one help on this...

Here is the code snippet for logout,

```
const { instance } = useMsal();
 const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
  if (isAuthenticated)
    instance.logoutRedirect();
```

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong, but it is normal behavior on single-sign-on. You login once per device and can use different applications without giving credentials again.. if you logout you logout this identity at all on that device. Test it with googlemail and youtube or something..

Answer (score 0):

MSAL.js logoutRedirect method in v2 - that **clears the cache in browser** storage and redirects the window to the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) sign-out page. After sign-out, Azure AD redirects back to the page that invoked logout by default.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript2#sign-out-with-a-popup-window

Comment: It is working perfectly fine without any issues.thanks